# How to change size of axis labels and values in seaborn pairsplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I've created a pairplot in seaborn using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

mtcars = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/focods/WonderfulML/master/data/mtcars.csv")
sns.pairplot(mtcars, kind='reg', diag_kind='hist')
```

and get this plot:

[image]

The font is tiny and I'm trying to figure out how to increase the size.  I see in the [documentation](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html?highlight=plot_kws) a parameter that might be what I'm looking for: **plot_kws** which is a dictionary, but how do I figure out the available keys and what they do?

So I have two questions.  First, is how to read the documentation so that I can figure out what the keys are for this dictionary.  Second, is how to increase the font size of the y-axis labels for this plot.

Answer (score 8):

Turns out that to change the size of x and y axis labels, I needed to call **set_context** and pass a dictionary to the **rc** parameter.  When I added this line just above the call to **pairplot**:

```
sns.set_context("paper", rc={"axes.labelsize":36})
```

I get this plot:

[image]

which is an improvement (if you look closely), but am now trying to figure out how to increase the size of the tick labels.

Comment: The rc parameters that control the size of the tick labels are `xtick.labelsize` and `ytick.labelsize`, you can modify them inside `set_context` as you did with `axes.labelsize`. An alternative is to use the `font_scale` parameter in `set_context` to rescale all the font sizes in the figure at once (see the relevant doc here: http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_context.html )

Comment: Thank Pablo.  How do I figure out what the allowable keys are for the rc dictionary?  The xtick and ytick.labelsize you provided worked great, but would like to learn how to navigate the doc's to be able to dig stuff like this out.  You know "Give a man a fish..." vs. "Teach a man to fish...".

Answer (score 0):

Resize the graph with all the parameters.

```
seabornInstance.set_context("paper", rc={"axes.labelsize":20})
seabornInstance.set_context("talk", font_scale=1.4)
xpl=seabornInstance.pairplot(mtcars, kind='reg', diag_kind='hist',height=7, aspect=1)
```